# Does anonymous and opaque moderation invite abuse of power?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Meet Bob. Bob posted 4 comments that were deleted without a notice or trace. There is no record of these deletions, for viewing by Bob or anyone else, nor apparently any way to know which moderators took the decision to censor them.

In law, a police who arrests or charges a suspect must sign their name, as must a judge giving a decision on a case.

In stack we elect moderators so why should we not be able to see their actions in their elected capacities?

Comment: The only question I see here is a feature request, which would only be entertained on [Meta.SE].  Meta.Law is for discussion particular to Law.SE.

Answer (score 8):

I just don't expect my comments to live on at all. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever. Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it can be deleted. Additionally, any comment that violates the comment guidelines listed above or the Code of Conduct is subject to deletion.
>
> In reality, on most sites, many since-obsolete or guideline-violating comments don't end up being deleted due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future

I understand that they're temporary and should generally be deleted, so I don't really care who deletes them or even why.

---

A bit more generally, I see you have asked a couple questions here recently about negative experiences you're having here. You have been around much longer than I, so maybe I am just naive, but I see this place as just a little Q&A forum :) Mods are volunteering to do a bunch of work to keep this site tidy and functional. I have enjoyed my time here so far and like being able to share a bit of my knowledge and expertise. I can't imagine it would be fun to get bogged down into concerns about voting patterns and moderator powers etc. Be curious, be helpful, and hope you can enjoy your time here. Apologies if this advice is unwelcome; I can delete it if so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139644/discussion-on-answer-by-jen-does-anonymous-and-opaque-moderation-invite-abuse-of).